# Is it possible to get different results for EMS using different methods?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

So induced emf in loop (circle of radius $a$) which rotates (with constant angular velocity $w$) on y-axis of coordinate system in homogeneous and constant magnetic filed B (parallel to z-axis) can be found using Faraday's law which gives
$ e = B \pi w a^2 \sin wt$

but when i try to find emf using formula
$ e =\oint_C ({\bf v} \times {\bf B})dl  $
I get slightly different result:

velocity of element of circle is

$v = w \cdot a \cdot \sin\alpha$

and angle between $ {\bf v} $ and $ {\bf B}$ is

$ \theta = w \cdot t$

and

$ d l  = a \cdot d \alpha $

For one fourth of circle I get

$ \frac{e}{4} = \int_{0}^{\frac{pi}{4}}a^2 Bw \cdot \sin wt  \cdot \sin\alpha \cdot d\alpha$

or

$ e = 4B w a^2 \sin wt$

for full circle.
Now, this is most likely impossible. 
I am obviously wrong somewhere. Where? :)

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that the integral is a *dot product* between $v\times B$ and $dl$. So the integrand will be multiplied by $cos(90-\alpha)=sin(\alpha)$ and the limits are $0$ and $2\pi$. Integration of $sin^2(\alpha)=\alpha/2-sin(2\alpha)/4$ which will give you the intended result.